# Why making a monoid instance is not a good idea

Tags: haskell

I have the following union operator designed in haskell:

```
data Set a = Set (a-> Bool)

union :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union (Set mem1) (Set mem2) = Set ( \x -> mem1 x || mem2 x)

instance Semigroup (Set a) where
  (<>) = union


instance Monoid (Set a) where
  mempty = Set ( \_ -> False)  -- Empty set identity element
  mappend = (<>)               -- Union monoid operation
```

I know that for a monoid instance it needs to hold for the associative and identity law. With a union operator, it does seem to satisfy that. What could be an issue by creating a monoid instance for this?

Comment: Why would there be an issue? You define a set, as the number of unions grow, it will slow down lookups, but I don't see any reason why this would not be a valid union. The point is that you here pick one, whereas another useful monoid could be the intersection.

Comment: I think it's OK. Just remember this set representation might not be very efficient. Evaluating `mempty <> ... <> mempty <> s` yields a slower version of `s`. Denotationally, it's the same function, but operationally it's slower.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you having a concrete issue? Are you soliciting feedback?

Answer (score 6):

The `Monoid` instance is indeed sound and valid. A possible issue is that you here use union as the `Monoid` instance, whether intersection is an equal valid one, and thus you pick one of the two.

Typically this is fixed by wrapping it in a new type, like:

```
newtype Union a = Union {unUnion :: Set a}
newtype Intersection a = Intersection {unIntersection :: Set a}

instance Semigroup (Union a) where
    (<>) = union

instance Semigroup (Intersection a) where
    (<>) = intersection

instance Monoid (Union a) where
    mempty = Union (Set (const False))

instance Monoid (Union a) where
    mempty = Intersection (Set (const True))
```

Here one can thus wrap the `Set` in a `Union` or `Intersection`, and then decide what monoid to use.